# Show loading dialog while uploading image to firebase storage

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, firebase-storage

I want to show a loading dialog while my app uploading an image into firebase storage. I don't have idea how to do something like this and i can't find any tutorial.

Note: i'm beginner on ios developent

Thanks :-)

Comment: Search harder. There are multiple tutorials showing how to setup a suitable model which has a "loading" state and how to render that state with an activity indicator when loading.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there are multiple tutorials in the web helping to solve this problem, possibly addressing only one certain aspect of a possible solution. The OP needs to focus on a specific issue.

Answer (score 1):

- You can use this cocoa pods library for showing loader with a message.

> pod 'SVProgressHUD'

- Here is a reference link :

> [SVProgressHUD](https://github.com/SVProgressHUD/SVProgressHUD)

- Import module in your file :

> import SVProgressHUD

- SVProgressHUD settings for iOS 13 or later in your AppDelegate file under

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
}
return true
```

Firebase Related Methods :

```
func uploadMedia(userId : String, image : UIImage, getController : UIViewController, completion: @escaping (_ url: String?) -> Void) {
    let storageRef = refs.storageRoot.child("images/\(userId)/\(NSUUID().uuidString)##images.jpeg")
    if let uploadData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5) {
        let metadata = StorageMetadata()
        metadata.contentType = "image/jpeg"
        storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: metadata) { (metadata, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("error")
                completion(nil)
            } else {
                storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
                    print(url?.absoluteString as Any)
                    completion(url?.absoluteString)
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage :

```
SVProgressHUD.show(withStatus: "Uploading Image")
self.uploadMedia(userId: 'userId', image: 'any UIImage') { url in
      SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
      print(url) //Your Firebase storage image url
      //Do your stuff here    
}
```

Comment: i added it, but i can't see any progress bar or something like this...

Comment: Which Xcode version and deployment target you are using?

Comment: I've edited my answer for SVProgreesHUD configuration for iOS 13 or later. You will see a progress view in center of the screen.